# How to add a uniqueness constraint on an Algolia index property?

Tags: algolia

We are running into issues where multiple workers add records for the same object to the [algolia](/questions/tagged/algolia) index.

Is there a way to set a constraint that would not allow to create two objects in the same index with the same value of a particular property?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you set an `objectID` attribute to your records, the API will update the existing record matching this `objectID` instead of creating a new one.

Any arbitrary string is an acceptable `objectID` so you could set it to the value of the property that uniquely identify your object (like its `id` in your own DB).

This way if you have several call pushing the exact same content, the first one will create it, and the other ones will simply overwrite it (with the same content, making it a no-op).